# Is it possible to merge these two functions as one calls on another

Tags: python-3.x, function, recursion

Would like to know if it is possible to merge these two functions together it seems like it could be a singular function through recursion but i'm not sure. I don't really do a lot of programming but this works as intended i just thought  it would be nice to have it as a single function. Just not sure how to program recursion any advice would be great thanks

```
def sieve(A, n):
       for i in A:
           if i % n == 0 and i > n:
               A.remove(i)
       return A


    def primelist(N):
        A = [i for i in range(2, N + 1)]
        for i in A:
            A = (sieve(A, i))
        print(A)
```

Decided on a new approach and solved:

```
def primelist(N):
    k = 0
    A = [i for i in range(2, N + 1)]
    while k < len(A):
        for i in A:
            if i % A[k] == 0 and i > A[k]:
                A.remove(i)
        k += 1
    return(A)
```

Comment: I don't see the primelist function being called, could you show where you called it and what output you got.

Comment: sieve gets called in the primelist function. So for example primelist(100) will give you the following array [2, 3, 5, 7, 11, 13, 17, 19, 23, 29, 31, 37, 41, 43, 47, 53, 59, 61, 67, 71, 73, 79, 83, 89, 97].

Comment: Managed to solve with applying brain power haha thanks for your time anyways

Comment: awesome, I gave it a try as well, check the answer. If you solved the same way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Decided on a new approach and solved:

We can do better -- your solution, and that of @ikuamike, have the same issue.  These lines in particular are inefficient:

```
for i in A:
    if i % A[k] == 0 and i > A[k]:
```

First, when possible, we should do an easier test *before* a harder test, so the `if` should really be:

```
for i in A:
    if i > A[k] and i % A[k] == 0:
```

to do the comparison (subtraction) test ahead of the modulus (division) test.  (Why do all those divisions when you don't need too?)

The next issue is that all the numbers from `A[0]` to `A[k]` don't need to be tested as they're eliminated by the comparison, so why not leave them out in the first place:

```
    for i in A[k + 1:]:
        if i % A[k] == 0:
```

Revised code:

```
def primelist(N):
    k = 0
    A = [i for i in range(2, N + 1)]

    while k < len(A):
        for i in A[k + 1:]:
            if i % A[k] == 0:
                A.remove(i)

        k += 1

    return A
```

With N set to 10,000, you can measure the time improvement.

Comment: Much appreciated your in depth comments and explanation . Best Regards

Answer (score 0):

```
def primelist(N):
    A = [i for i in range(2, N + 1)]
    new_a = A
    for i in A:
        for n in new_a:
            if n % i == 0 and n > i:
                new_a.remove(n)
    print(new_a)
```

This should work well for you, I just replaced the for loop in seive onto the primelist function.